# How to use iframe in progressive mobile application?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, progressive-web-apps

I have a pwa mobile application which use iframe to show preview of pdf. The same code works fine when in desktop mode but in mobile version it shows a blank screen with open button. Is there any work around to preview pdf in pwa mobile application.[image: preview of pdf]

The above code works fine in desktop

Comment: how an iframe is rendered depends on the browser. Most browsers on android do not let the user preview the pdf and instead download it instantly, hence this functionality can not be available on mobile (via iframe, there might be other methods)

Comment: You could consider using a JavaScript control to display a preview of the PDF in your mobile app. For example, the LEADTOOLS [HTML5 Document Viewer](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/javascript/to/using-the-leadtools-document-viewer.html) control is able to render PDF files whether on desktop or mobile using JavaScript. (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor).